# Paragraph in from reportlab.platypus PDF PYTHON - wrap Text go down

Tags: python, pdf, canvas, reportlab, paragraph

I'm creating a software that when you write everything, generate a PDF.
I'm using Python, Tkinter and the follows modoles: ParagraphStyle,Paragraph

See My code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import  A4

my_Style=ParagraphStyle(name='CustomStyle',
                        parent=getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal'],
                        spaceAfter=12,  # Space after the paragraph
                        spaceBefore=12,  # Space before the paragraph
                        fontSize=12,
                        backColor='green',
                        wordWrap='hyphen',
                        leading=14,
                        borderColor='green',
                        textColor='black',
                        borderTopStyle='dotted',  # Top border line style (e.g., 'solid', 'dashed', 'dotted')
                        alignment=0)  # or 'bottom'


width,height=A4
my_path='my_pdf.pdf'
c = canvas.Canvas(my_path, pagesize=A4)

#O quebra liinha não é feito pelo drwaOn, mas sim pelo o estilo
p1=Paragraph('''começa aqui: \n<b>About this online classes </b><BR/>\
     Welcome to our online classes.<BR/> \
     You can l \
SQLite and many more \
<font face="times" color="blue">We are creating \
PDF bytLab</font> \
<i>This is part of our Final report.</i>''',my_Style)

#Place our Paragraph on the canvas like this.
p1.wrapOn(c,300,0)
p1.drawOn(c,15,400)
c.save()
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('my_pdf.pdf')
```

How can you see, will generate a PDF like the follow first image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kctt.png)

So far so good. But, when there are less characters, the break line go up and not down. Look to the second image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKvju.png)

Everywhere, when you type, the text goes down. In that case, it goes up. How to make paragraph default?

I've change wordWrap configure,parent,alignment configure and nothing happen.

Comment: No matter if is a html page. The Paragraph function wrap to the next line when it reaches the right edge of the container. But, the actual line goes up and next down.  I want the line to stay still.